# Unable to bind datasource to reportViewer

Tags: c#, reporting-services, reportviewer

I have a  C# application that uses a `reportViewer`. I want to add 3 reports in a single `reportViewer`. Here is the code for a single report:

```
ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource();
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
if (comboBoxReports.SelectedIndex == 0)
{
    reportViewer1.Reset();
    reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "D:\\AMOS\\WindowsFormsApplication1\\WindowsFormsApplication1\\Report2.rdlc";
    rds.Name = "First_Year_IT_AttendanceBindingSource";
    rds.Value = this.First_Year_IT_AttendanceBindingSource;
    reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);  
    this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
}
```

However when I run my application, I get the following error

> A data source instance has not been supplied for the data source 'DataSet1'

What can be the possible mistake?

Comment: Maybe it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802707/setting-the-datasource-for-a-local-report-net-report-viewer help you to find answer

Comment: Name of rds must match the DataSource in the RDLC

Answer (score 2):

1. Open rdlc file as text
2. Replace **DataSet1** with **First_Year_IT_AttendanceBindingSource**

Check that the columns (fields) in rdlc is 'equal' to columns in your data source