# How to pass parameters to a Local report that has object data source in asp.net web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services

I want to pass parameters to local reports that have Object Data source(gets list of data from c#method that needs parameters) , how can I do that ?

```
    #region Parameterized Report
            ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
            string FolderPath = Server.MapPath("~/LocalReports");
            string ReportName = "ParameterizedReportWizard.rdlc";
            string DataSetName = "DataSet1Parameter";
            string SelectedMethod = "GetSomeEmployees";
            string Parameter = "ID";

            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Path.Combine(FolderPath, ReportName);
            ObjectDataSource objDataSource = new ObjectDataSource() { ID = DataSetName, TypeName = "BussinessLogic.Custom", SelectMethod = SelectedMethod};
            ReportParameter p1 = new ReportParameter("ReportParameter1", "1"); //I pass the same parameter name tha exist in report definition and it's value is on 1 as  static value for now

            this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { p1});

            ReportDataSource datasource = new ReportDataSource(DataSetName, objDataSource);
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource);

            #endregion
```

Comment: Here's a related post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802707/setting-the-datasource-for-a-local-report-net-report-viewer

Comment: But My case is that the method -that return my list of objects= has parameters , how can i do that, plz help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All data access for local reports should be performed before binding it to your report. If possible, filter at the source.

You need to add to the `ObjectDataSource.SelectParameter` collection.

```
string DataSetName = "DataSet1Parameter";
string SelectedMethod = "GetSomeEmployees";
string Parameter = "ID";

ObjectDataSource objDataSource = new ObjectDataSource() { ID = DataSetName, TypeName = "BussinessLogic.Custom", SelectMethod = SelectedMethod};
    objDataSource.SelectParameters.Add(new Parameter("id"));
```

then subscribe to the `ObjectDataSource.Selecting` event to set the parameter.

```
protected void objDataSource_Selecting
    (object sender, ObjectDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
{
    e.InputParameters["id"] = "1";
}
```

Comment: What about displaying the parameters in the report? should i add the parametes controls mannally or it can be automatically generated as it has been happened in case of the report server???????

Comment: your parameters have to be in your report definition to use them in your report, so add them in normally.

Comment: okay ,Actually i did that in the report definition. but SetParameters() still cannot help me?!

Comment: can you update your post to show how you are setting your parameters?

Comment: I have updated it and  I have get thhis error after run  :"An error has occurred during report processing.
ObjectDataSource 'DataSet1Parameter' could not find a non-generic method 'GetSomeEmployees' that has no parameters."

Comment: It looks like the error is happening when the `ObjectDataSource` is trying to call the GetSomeEmployees method and you are not passing a parameter. See my updated answer.

Comment: Dear Sir Cam Bruce, I want to thank u , and i'll mark you answer as correct one But for now u now that  we have passed hard coded parameter value what if i want to make it user defined???? Many Thanks in advance :)

Comment: That parameter does not need to be hard coded. It can be anything (drop down value on your aspx page, query string from page, etc)

Comment: I got your  point but do you know if there is any way to make it auto generated as The same case when I deploy  my ssrs reports on the report server?

Comment: That is the limitation of local reports. You have to perform the data access for your parameters yourself. i.e binding the data to dropdowns.