# Integrate an SSRS with a C# app

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, reporting-services, sql-server-2012-datatools

I have a SSRS solution with a report and I'd like to integrate that report with an C# app that is in another solution. Could anybody you tell me how can I do that?, I'm using visual studio 2010.

Comment: Is it a web app or winforms?

Comment: The `ReportViewer` Control comes in web and [winforms flavours](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337089.aspx). You'll need to setup approprate credentials to access your SSRS Server and set the control to `ProcessingMode.Remote`. [This example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8802707/314291) is for local client, but gives you an idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ReportViewer](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6442) component allows you to add a report to a winform application, or you can always launch a web browser out of your application to the report server, passing parameters as needed.

Comment: +1 for suggesting to just add a web browser control and set the URL programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

I did it, I copy the xml (.rdl file) from my SQL Server Data Tools pasted it in my .rdlc faile created in my C# app, after that I updated this line

```
<Report xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition">
```

from 2010 to 2008 and after that change my dataset name.