# How to develop client side SSRS report using Reports Builder 3.0 and embed in ReportViewer?

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc, rdl

Sorry for being a newbie to SSRS.

My design goal:

Near term: develop - using SSRS - a simple client side (no reporting server!) report - based on MS SQL data tables, and embed it into the .NET WPF client (application)

Long term: for additional reports, hire external SSRS experts, so they will provide the reports developed, and I will integrate them into the same WPF application.

I managed to do 2 things:

1. Develop a simple report connecting to MS SQL, using Reports Builder 3.0 - as a result, an **RDL** file was generated (the file contains all the DB connections)
2. Embed a **ReportViewer** WinForms control into the WPF application.

**Unfortunately, I wasn't able to load the report I developed, into the application.**

I understood from articles on the new that RDL is not designed to support client-side execution (without a server), and RDLC should be used instead. However, I wasn't able to figure out how to conver the report to RDLC, using the Reports Builder - it does not give me an option to save in a different format.

I would appreciate any hint from the experienced people on how to accomplish my goal.

Specifically, should I use RDLC, and if positive - what's the way to get the report in this format?

Thanks
Max

Comment: You should be using the local report settings instead of server reports settings on the report viewer control.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend using **Visual Studio** when creating RDLC reports that will be embedded within an application and run in "Local" mode, and using either **Microsoft Report Builder** or **Visual Studio** to create RDL reports that will run in "Server" mode within SSRS.

A RDLC report would be created within a WPF Visual Studio project be simply creating a new Report.

A RDL report would be created within a Reports Server project when using Visual Studio.

Alternatively, it appears you could simply rename the file from RDL to RDLC if you don't mind manually correcting the Data Source information in the report definition file: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252109(v=vs.120).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252109%28v=vs.120%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. I was able to develop an RDLC report using VS, and load the data. However, I had to load the "DataSet" in my code, as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802707/setting-the-datasource-for-a-local-report-net-report-viewer  . Based on the logic that report developer already did some work with the DB (and on my prior experience with Crystal Reports) - I would expect only to set the SQL Connection String. Is it doable with SSRS? Thanks

Comment: As you've found RDLC reports must be bound to a DataTable [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252094.aspx). On the other hand RDL reports contain both the report format and SQL queries.