# C# Winforms binding a DataTable to a ReportrViewer control

Tags: c#, winforms, binding, datatable, reportviewer

I'm having some problems trying to bind a dataTable to a ReportViewer control in a Winform using c#.

I have spent ALOT of time trawling through this and other forums looking for solutions, but alas no found so far.
I have put debug markers into my code and can 'see' the finished dataTable with the correct 2x2 array summary report. But when I try to bind the dataTable to the ReportViewer object, I get a blank screen. I'm SURE there's something simple missing in my coding, but cannot see what it is!!!

Here's more details of my reporting form:

1. I have 2 global fields defined as follows:

> ```
>     /*create global dataTable */
>     DataTable _dTable = new DataTable("dtQOPS3710");
>
>     /* create a new Dataset...*/
>     Dataset _dSet = new Dataset("psysReporting.dSetReportViewer.xsd");
> ```

And here is the code I use to build the dataTable and bind it to the ReportViewer:

> /*add columns to the dataTable (10 in total)*/
>
> ```
>         _dTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Nationality", typeof(String)));
>         _dTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Total_Females", typeof(String)));
>         _dTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Total_Males", typeof(String)));
>         _dTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Elig.55", typeof(String)));
>         _dTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Elig.56", typeof(String)));
>         _dTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Elig.57", typeof(String)));
>         _dTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Elig.58", typeof(String)));
>         _dTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Elig.25", typeof(String)));
>         _dTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Elig.26", typeof(String)));
>         _dTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Total_Patients", typeof(String)));
>
>         /* now add the rows */
>         for (int i = 0; i < _intMaxNoOfRows; i++)
>         {
>             DataRow dataRow = _dTable.NewRow();
>
>             for (int j = 0; j < _maxJ; j++)
>             {
>                 if (strArrayList[i, 1] != string.Empty)   /* column 1 = Nationality */
>                     dataRow[j] = strArrayList[i, j];
>             }
>
>             if (strArrayList[i, 1] != string.Empty)        /* column 1= Nationality */
>             {
>                _dTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);  
>             }
>
>         }
>
>         // add datatable '_dTable' to dataset '_dSet'...
>         _dSet.Tables.Add(_dTable); 
>
>         // bind dataSet to report viewer
>         this.reportViewer1.Reset();
>         this.reportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
>         this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "psysReporting.Report1.rdlc";
>         this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
>         this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource(_dTable.TableName, _dTable));
>
>         this.reportViewer1.Refresh();
> ```

As I stated above, I've tried debugging the code and I can see the correct report in the dataTable, but it seems the binding isn't working!  I don't get any errors when running the code!

Any help would be MUCH appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed to explicitly bind the data at the end (before refresh()):

```
this.reportViewer1.DataBind();
```

Check `StuartLC` answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802707/setting-the-datasource-for-a-local-report-net-report-viewer).

---

Another point. Your `for` loop can be optimized. Testing nationnality does not depend on the loop variable `j`. Try this (no link with your question, just saying):

```
// now add the rows
for (int i = 0; i < _intMaxNoOfRows; i++)
{
    // column 1 = Nationality
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strArrayList[i, 1]))
    {
        var dataRow = _dTable.NewRow();
        for (int j = 0; j < _maxJ; j++)
            dataRow[j] = strArrayList[i, j];

        _dTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);  
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, so I added the following line to my code as you suggested:    this.reportViewer1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding(_dTable.TableName, _dTable, _dTable.ToString())); 
 
            this.reportViewer1.Refresh();        I get following error when I run the app. :Cannot bind to the property 'dtQOPS3710' on the target control.
Parameter name: PropertyName                    How do I get the propertyname of my DataTable?

Comment: So, this question is resolved? Mark the answer please. If you have another issue (as described with your property "dtQOPS3710") open another question with all the details.

Comment: I resolved this problem by exporting the datagridview to an Excel workbook! Works just fine!