# use a master report viewer to show all reports in RDLC

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataset, reportviewer, rdlc

I am trying a to make a report viewer that's gonna show all the reports in the same viewer. I used to make individual report viewer for every RDLC. but that's really a long-process. And kinda stupid.

I have the dataSet in App_Code folder using Table Adapter and i want to take that dataset as the ReportDatasource and use cases for different reports. But I dont know how to. Whatever I got on the internet is doing it using SQL command. But I have the connection and stored procedures ready in DataSet. I want to use that dataset.

Very new to .NET developement, sorry if I am not clear.

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8802923/314291) should help - embed all of the RDLC's into an assembly, and set the `LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource` to the fully qualified name of the resource. Then add a `ReportDataSource` with the same name as defined in the binding, add parameters, and you should be good.

Comment: Thank you. I did it. the problem was that I was trying to get the data from the dataset.xsd not the tableAdapter. gonna try the assembly later. thanks a lot.:)

Comment: The answer is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8802923/314291). Thanks @StuartLC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do something like:

```
DataSet ds = SomeMethodToRetrieveDataSet(); // e.g. via DataAdapter
// Set parameters, 
ReportParameter[] parameters = new ReportParameter[...];  
ReportDataSource reportDataSource = new ReportDataSource();
//match the DataSource in the RDLC
reportDataSource.Name = "ReportData"; 
reportDataSource.Value = ds.Tables[0];

// Addparameters to the collection
reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(parameters); 
reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource);
reportViewer1.DataBind();
```

Comment: You just copied it from @**StuartLC**'s link. dont do it. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Maybe I copied from that link the time I needed it but in this answer I copied it from my own code. Thanks for advice though and -1 :)