# How to make a SSRS work for multiple users

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, reporting-services

I can't find anything on this so I don't think I am asking the question right but here is my situation.  I have a stored procedure which the end user passes a list of filter criteria, since I don't know what the filter criteria will be I used dynamic SQL.  Further, to allow for more than one user to run the stored procedure concurrently I used all dynamically named temp tables so there would be no collisions.  That all works.

Now my problem is how to output the report.  Right now I have a SSRS report pointing to a single database that the stored procedure dumps its output to.  When the stored procedure finishes the report is displayed.  This works for one user but if two users run the stored procedure at the same time I have no way of knowing which output data will show on the report.  Complicating issues is the dynamic user filter criteria can greatly effect the time the stored procedure takes to complete.  I can see the report loading data just as the other stored procedure session is truncating or loading data to the output table.

I can queue up requests and run them one at a time but ideally I want them to be able to run concurrently as several users have to run this report many times at the beginning of each month.  Is there a way to ensure that the data displayed on the report to the end user matches the data output from the stored procedure session the user ran.

EDIT:

The following is not a requirement but to clarify how this works now, the end user goes to an web site, enters in some filter criteria into a bunch of text boxes, one for each filterable database field, using a third parties search wildcards format that they already know.  I then take that input, clean it up and parse it into a SQL `WHILE` string which is then passed to the stored procedure that gets the data.  When the stored procedure finishes control is passed back to the website that then displays the report as an imbedded object.  So the website is calling the parsing method, the stored procedure and the report.

Comment: Will the actual outputted name and number of columns vary between users or report execution?

Comment: Instead of putting the data in a table, can't you put the result data in a #TEMP table? The report will use the #TEMP table associated with their session.

Comment: @Vinnie the outputted data will always have the same table structure.

Comment: @HannoverFist that would be great but I don't know how I would do that.  Can you change the data source of a report when you call it?  Also, wont the #TEMP be out of scope for the report?

Comment: If your dataset's query creates a **#Temp** table (not **##Temp**) and uses it with a `SELECT * FROM #Temp` , only that session's #Temp table would be available. Any other user would be kept separate in their own #Temp table. If your SP takes a long time, their may still be conflicts - you might re-work your SP to use #Temp tables.

Comment: @HannoverFist are you assuming I am calling the stored procedure as the data source for the report?

Comment: As far as I can tell, your report's dataset calls a stored procedure that populates a table then uses that table as the source. Can't you just put the data from the static table into a #Temp and use the #Temp as the source?

Comment: @HannoverFist I edited the question to add more detail but in short this is not how it works currently.  It would take some reworking to do it the way you are thinking but it might work.  I will play with it tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server will create a separate session for each report user. It will then invoke the stored procedure in its own session (SQL Server is a multi session product) and using the selected parameters will run the proc and produce unique results which will then be passed back to the report user  who invoked it and the report will then be shown to the user. If ten users simultaneously invoke the report, with unique parameters, they will each see a different report in the body of the report.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up reworking the whole thing as Benjamin suggested and it works fine but that really was not the answer I was looking for.  I finally stumbled upon it while researching something else.  You can set the report viewer's `DataSources.Add()` method to add your own dataset.  This would have allowed me to run the stored procedure in the webpage so I can catch and handle the errors at the webpage level so I could give more useful feedback to the end users.  You can see this other post [setting the datasource for a local report net report viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802707/setting-the-datasource-for-a-local-report-net-report-viewer) for more detail.

The example is for a local report but I was able to get it to work on a remote report but I am on a trusted internal only network.  As I understand it, you can also do it with the newer report viewers too.