# Report Viewer parameter not giving expected values

Tags: model-view-controller, rdlc

I am new in this field, I am using report viewer 11.0 with mvc5.

I have used a parameter with name "Id" in table control in Report.

[image]

I used This code to pass value in Report :-

```
List<ReportParameter> rp = new List<ReportParameter>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                    {
                        rp.Add(new ReportParameter("Id",  "A-"+i.ToString() ));
                    }

                    reportViewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(rp.ToArray());
```

**and I get this OutPut :-**

[image]

**But i want this output :-**

[image]

what is wrong with my code ?
Please Help ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign only single value to the report's parameter, this is why parameters are not really suitable for any structured data with multiple and variable values.

You can read more about use of the report parameters here: [Report Parameters (Report Builder and Report Designer)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/report-parameters-report-builder-and-report-designer)

What you need is to add those values into single column DataTable or other object and supply it as DataSource to your report. Here is an example of how to use custom data as s report data source: [Using Custom Data Source to create RDLC Reports](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/473844/Using-Custom-Data-Source-to-create-RDLC-Reports) and more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802707/setting-the-datasource-for-a-local-report-net-report-viewer).